# Parse Web Site HTML with JAVA

Tags: java, html, scrape

I want to parse a simple web site and scrape information from that web site.

I used to parse XML files with DocumentBuilderFactory, i tried to do the same thing for the html file but it always get into an infinite loop.

```
    URL url = new URL("http://www.deneme.com");
    URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(input);
    String inputLine;

     FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("orhancan");
     PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(inputLine);
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();

    File fXmlFile = new File("orhancan");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);


    NodeList prelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("body");
    System.out.println(prelist.getLength());
```

Whats is the problem? Or is there any easier way to scrape data from a web site for a given html tag?

Comment: Firstly you can use a String instead of a File. Where does it enter in an infinite loop ? Maybe because of the input stream from the url which doesn't seem to end you have that problem.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There is a much easier way to do this. I suggest using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/). With JSoup you can do things like

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```

Or if you want the body:

```
Elements body = doc.select("body");
```

Or if you want all links:

```
Elements links = doc.select("body a");
```

You no longer need to get connections or handle streams. Simple. If you have ever used jQuery then it is very similar to that.

Comment: First, thank you ! But what is #mp-itn b a ?

Comment: #mp-itn is just a container with `id="mp-itn"`

Comment: See my edit. Understanding how css selectors work would really help you.

Comment: OK, http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation this was really what I need, thanks.

Comment: A library is a better choice than raw code, I would go for it

Comment: One question. What `Jsoup` mean? like `DNS` is Domain Name System. What's `Jsoup`?

Answer (score 22):

Definitely [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) is the answer. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

HTML is not always valid, well-formatted XML. Try a special HTML parser instead of an XML parser. There are a couple of different ones available:

http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers