# How to copy certain text from a website with Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, copy-paste

I have a website that is in plain text. The website is in a format like this:

> {"code1":"Text I want copied","code2":"Second text I want to copy"}

Every time the website refreshes though, the texts I want copied change in length. I am curious how I could retrieve the text starting after ' **:"** ' and before ' **",** ', using Java. I want the same thing to happen with the second text as well. I also would like to remove the html tags. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that text you mention is in JSON format. Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Still don't understand how I can parse it from the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) library, you could parse the JSON like:

```
String myJSONString = "{\"code1\":\"Text I want copied\",\"code2\":\"Second text I want to copy\"}";
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(myJSONString);
String[] keys = JSONObject.getNames(object);

String firstText = (String) object.get(keys[0]);
String secondText = (String) object.get(keys[1]);
```

For parsing the web page, you can use the [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) library. See an example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071598/1461484).