# regex repeat group

Tags: regex

I am trying to capture the url of the images (how ever many there may be on a specific site. I am able to do so however when I then progress to try an capture other things thereafter the entire thing falls apart. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Working regex:

```
.(?:src="(http:\/\/website\.bla\.com\/Live.+?)".+?)
```

Non working

```
.(?:src="(http:\/\/website\.bla\.com\/Live.+?)".+?).*Status.*\s(Sld|Rtr)
```

Sample code:

```
 <div ng-class="{
    'active': active
  }" class="item text-center ng-isolate-scope" ng-transclude="" ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                          <img class="image-circle ng-scope" ng-src="http://website.bla.com/Live/photos/FULL/18/134/W3764134_18.jpg" src="http://website.bla.com/Live/photos/FULL/18/134/W3764134_18.jpg">
                  </div><!-- end ngRepeat: slide in slides --><div ng-class="{
    'active': active
  }" class="item text-center ng-isolate-scope" ng-transclude="" ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                          <img class="image-circle ng-scope" ng-src="http://website.bla.com/Live/photos/FULL/19/134/W3764134_19.jpg" src="http://website.bla.com/Live/photos/FULL/19/134/W3764134_19.jpg">
                  </div><!-- end ngRepeat: slide in slides --><div ng-class="{
    'active': active
  }" class="item text-center ng-isolate-scope" ng-transclude="" ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                          <img class="image-circle ng-scope" ng-src="http://website.bla.com/Live/photos/FULL/20/134/W3764134_20.jpg" src="http://website.bla.com/Live/photos/FULL/20/134/W3764134_20.jpg">
                  </div><!-- end ngRepeat: slide in slides -->
                </div>
<b class="ng-binding">Status:</b> &nbsp; &nbsp; Sld
```

Comment: don't parse html with regex, use xml parsers. What is your OS?

Comment: try alternates: https://regex101.com/r/sHWJMi/1 for this example. But seriously this can get complicated.

Comment: What language is the regex in? Why do you have the non-capturing group around the whole thing? Why the `.` at the front? How are you matching across newlines?

Comment: Its in php, the . at the front helped at some point in testing but is not necessary. OS is windows for testing but Linux for deployed env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this simple example: use alternates. Please see [this](https://regex101.com/r/sHWJMi/1).

But this can get complicated if added requirements are to be implemented. In that case you might want to use a HTML parser as in JSoup.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071568/parse-web-site-html-with-java) one - it is already answered:

Answer (score 0):

With lots of assumptions, you could try this:

```
src="(http://website\.bla\.com/Live.+?)"(?:(?:[^s]|s[^r]|sr[^c])*?Status.*? (Sld|Rtr))?
```